# How redux-thunk works?

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-thunk

So I am currently new with redux and stuck in the middleware part. I need to know how these two codes interact with each other.

My action creator:

```
import jsonPlaceHolder from '../APis/jsonPlaceHolder';

export const fetchPosts= ()=>{

  return async (dispatch)=>{

      const response = await jsonPlaceHolder.get('/posts');

      dispatch({type:'FETCH_POSTS',payload: response});

  };

};
```

redux-thunk code:

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}

const thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
thunk.withExtraArgument = createThunkMiddleware;

export default thunk;
```

Answer (score 3):

Plain redux only works with sync actions. Redux thunk gives you the ability to work with async actions (to dispatch multiple actions from a single action creator, for async actions that is usually the REQUEST/RESPONSE/ERROR action). Middleware is something that stands between you dispatching the action and reducer updating the store. Since redux only works with plain objects, to use a action creator (like fetchPosts) you need something (redux-thunk here). It simply injects the dispatch parameter (and getState that gives you the ability to get the current state if your action creator depends on it).

The **next(action)** inside middleware is the method that propagates your action object to the next middleware(or if it is the last one to your reducer). Redux-thunk checks if the thing you dispatched is a function(since we said that redux can only work with plain objects), and if it is a function it just injects the above mentioned parameters.

So it is basically:

> dispatch(fetchPosts()) -> redux-thunk-middleware -> it is function so
>   lt's call it with injected dispatch/getState (this will not be propagated to the reducer) ->
>   dispatch({type:'FETCH_POSTS',payload: response}) ->
>   redux-thunk-middleware -> not a function, let it through -> reducer ->
>   update state

Hope this helps.